# Is there a glossary of the properties returned in response to the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: support, api

While most items are self-explanatory, some aren't, and I was wondering if there was a glossary explaining all the properties in each of the response types?

Answer (score 2):

The API documentation does do this somewhat, more below, but needs improvement.
There is a [feature request to allow users to edit the documentation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290167/allow-users-to-edit-the-api-documentation).  Please go upvote that now.

Anyway, **each of the properties is listed in the documentation of the object that contains it.**
For example [the `badge` object](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge) (Click for larger view):

[image: Sample object page]

Each object page shows:

- A general overview of the object.
- A list of properties ("Fields") that are potentially returned.
- The type of those properties, whether they are returned by default, and whether they need an authenticated user to access (denoted with `private_info`).
- Examples of the output/return of the object.
- A list of methods (AKA "routes" or "queries") that return the object type.

Rarely, you can get more information about a particular property if it is documented in [the data-dump schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede), but this is very hit or miss.

---

**The object documentation pages are linked from the method/route documentation page(s) that return(s) said object.**
For example, from [the `/badges/name` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/badges-by-name):

[image: Badges!? Here's your badges.]

Unfortunately, that seems to be the only way to get to these pages; there is no central list.

So, here is **a list of the available object pages** (API version 2.2):

- [*Wrapper Object*](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wrapper) (This is the parent/root container for everything else/below.)
- [access_token](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/access-token)
- [account_merge](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/account-merge)
- [answer](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/answer)
- [badge](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge)
- [badge_count](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/badge-count)
- [closed_details](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/closed-details)
- [comment](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/comment)
- [error](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/error)
- [event](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/event)
- [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/filter)
- [flag_option](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/flag-option)
- [inbox_item](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/inbox-item)
- [info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/info)
- [migration_info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/migration-info)
- [network_activity](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-activity)
- [network_post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-post)
- [network_user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-user)
- [notice](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notice)
- [notification](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification)
- [original_question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/original-question)
- [post](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/post)
- [privilege](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/privilege)
- [question](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question)
- [question_timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/question-timeline)
- [related_site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/related-site)
- [reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation)
- [reputation_history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/reputation-history)
- [revision](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/revision)
- [search_excerpt](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/search-excerpt)
- [shallow_user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user)
- [site](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/site)
- [styling](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/styling)
- [suggested_edit](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/suggested-edit)
- [tag](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag)
- [tag_score](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag-score)
- [tag_synonym](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag-synonym)
- [tag_wiki](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/tag-wiki)
- [top_tag](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/top-tag)
- [user](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user)
- [user_timeline](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user-timeline)
- [write_permission](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/write-permission)

Answer (score 0):

There is no such glossary in the [official API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/).

The fields used in the API are similar (but not identical) to those in SEDE and the public data dump, so you might have some luck in the [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677/295232). Not all fields are documented there, but because that Q&A is publicly editable (unlike the API documentation), we (the Stack Exchange community) can easily add some clarification if necessary.