# Can we find the time of a vote using the API?

Tags: support, api, api-v2.2

I've been looking at the API docs and more specifically at the filters available for the [`/answers/{ids}`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids), [`/posts/{ids}`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-by-ids) and [`/questions/{ids}`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids) routes but can't find anything other than `upvoted` and `downvoted`.

Is it possible to find out the date a user voted on a post using the API (with any type of access token scope)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, vote time data is sensitive and [censored to protect voter anonymity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/933/why-is-vote-time-missing-in-the-se-data-dump-and-sede).

So, scanning [the list of available objects in the API](https://stackapps.com/a/7686/7653), we see that:

1. A **user's downvote** times can be obtained via [the `/users/{id}/reputation-history/full` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/full-reputation-history) for the **authenticated user only**.
   (Even for downvotes that cost no reputation)
2. There is **no object** that returns a **user's upvote** times.
   Currently, your only recourse is to log into the website and scrape the
     https://stackapps.com/users/current?tab=votes&sort=upvote
   pages.
3. **Question up/down vote** times, ***normalized and aggregated to midnight*** can be had via [the `/questions/{ids}/timeline` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-timeline#pagesize=100&ids=6091&filter=!6JE_AUixqf1)D&site=stackapps&run=true).
4. **Answer up/down vote** times are only available as a subset of the parent question's timeline.
5. You cannot see voting time information for anybody but yourself (or the authenticated user), via any means (Website, API, SEDE, Data Dump).